# Trouble Mounting Raid5 Hardware Array

Tags: mount, raid

In my homelab have a Dell R720 server with an H710 RAID controller installed. I built a Raid5 array using the onboard controller with 8 4TB HDDs. I was able to create a partition in fdisk without any issue, but when I go to mount it I receive the following error message:

```
~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/raid_array/

mount: /mnt/raid_array: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it. I'm almost certain it's not a bad filesystem, but I'll include screenshots of everything I can think of as relevant.

Here's lsblk:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop1    7:1    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2246
loop2    7:2    0  32.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13270
loop3    7:3    0  32.5M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13640
loop4    7:4    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1169
loop5    7:5    0  67.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21545
loop6    7:6    0  69.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19188
sda      8:0    0  25.5T  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0  25.5T  0 part
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   499M  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0    99M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part
└─sdb4   8:20   0 465.5G  0 part /
```

Here's fdisk -l

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 55.45 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.51 MiB, 58191872 bytes, 113656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 32.42 MiB, 33980416 bytes, 66368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 32.45 MiB, 34017280 bytes, 66440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 61.85 MiB, 64835584 bytes, 126632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 67.26 MiB, 70516736 bytes, 137728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 69.9 MiB, 73277440 bytes, 143120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 25.48 TiB, 28001576157184 bytes, 54690578432 sectors
Disk model: PERC H710
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B6301972-E216-2E4B-8F60-D70B8A116804

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 54690578398 54690576351 25.5T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: PNY CS900 1TB SS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 21B6CED0-2E4A-4AD4-8B1D-4A7A51F65B9B

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2  1024000   1226751    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  1226752   1259519     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4  1259520 977397759 976138240 465.5G Microsoft basic data
```

And fstab:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/148121e8-c77f-4b6d-a389-c3a37b2379e5 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9CBB-B356 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0

# MythosRaid
UUID=B6301972-E216-2E4B-8F60-D70B8A116804 /mnt/raid_array ext4 defaults 0 0
```

If there's anything else I can include, please let me know, appreciate any help y'all can give!

Comment: Please add which version of Ubuntu you’re using, thanks!

Comment: Sorry! This is in 20.04.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `/dev/sda` is the presentation of your Hardware RAID. I would say that it looks like you have not yet created a filesystem on your virtual disk.

```
mkfs.ext4 -L bigdata /dev/sda1
mount /dev/sda1/mnt                           # mount it
```

But before you do, consider whether you would prefer to have a filesystem that's 25TB or whether it would be more useful to have that assigned as a logical space (LVM) from which you can carve filesystems as necessary

```
pvcreate /dev/sda1                            # disk partition to use
vgcreate myvg /dev/sda1                       # "myvg" is name of the logical volume group
lvcreate /dev/myvg --name mylv --size 100G    # "mylv" is logical disk volume
mkfs.ext4 -L myext4 /dev/myvg/mylv            # create filesystem
mount /dev/myvg/mylv /mnt                     # mount it
```

The key to success with LVM is not to assign the entire space to a single filesystem, but to grow it (within reason) as required.

Comment: The philosophy of use for this system (at least in my mind) would be to have a large pool that I would use to regularly write backups to from my everyday use desktop/laptop/etc. The main reason I decided on RAID 5 was for the parity in case of a drive failure. In your opinion, would an LVM be better for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Also, thank you for the help!

Comment: On my 12TB x8 array I run RAID 6. My concern is to protect the disks as best as possible during a rebuild

Comment: I'd still probably go with LVM, and grow the space for the backups drive in, say, 5TB units. But I can't really give you advice without knowing the whole story behind your requirements, and that's not appropriate for you to share here